# How do I use API versioning?

Tags: 7, services

I'm using the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) to produce a REST API.  According to the official documentation, there is a way to [version services resources](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/docs/services.versions.api.php?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-3.x).  I believe version here means supplying a single API (e.g. `example.com/api`) and allowing clients to specify which version they want per resource with headers.

So I think that means that these two requests would return different results, despite living at the same URL:

Version 1.0:

```
POST /api/v1/system/set_variable HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Version 1.2:

```
POST /api/v1/system/set_variable HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
services_system_set_variable_version: 1.2
```

I cannot make this work for the life of me.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Enabled the system/set_variable service
   [image: system]
2. Added the following code to mymodule.module (cribbed directly from services.versions.api.php)

.

```
function _system_resource_set_variable_update_1_1() {
  $new_set = array(
    'help' => 'Create a node with an nid test',
  );
  return $new_set;
}

function _system_resource_set_variable_update_1_2() {
  $new_set = array(
    'help' => 'Create a node with an nid optional prams.',
    'args' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'source' => array('data' => 'name'),
        'description' => t('The name of the variable to set.'),
        'type' => 'string',
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'value',
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'source' => array('data' => 'value'),
        'description' => t('The value to set.'),
        'type' => 'string',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $new_set;
}
```

3. Cleared cache
4. Attempted to use the system/set_variable service with postman.
5. Saw that the system/set_variable service was working
   [image: postman]
6. Attempted to use the system/set_variable  service without arguments, per `_system_resource_set_variable_update_1_2`
7. Saw that arguments were still required
   [image: postman1]

So what am I doing wrong here?  I'm pretty sure I followed all the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from services.versions.api.php

> For clients that want to request a specific version they need to pass a certain header
>
> - services_RESOURCE_METHOD_version = version
> - as an example, services_system_set_variable_version = 1.2
> - @see ServicesVersionTests for code examples

Make sure to use set acceptable Content-Type.

> ```
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> ```

```
GET /v1/status HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
API-KEY: AAAAAAA
TOKEN: VVVVVVV
services_status_index_version: 1.1
Host: local.mywebsite.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.0.16 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.6) GCDHTTPRequest
```